# Deploying a web application on the IIS 5

Tags: asp.net, iis-5

I am in the process of deploying a web application on IIS5 on my server which runs windows XP.So when i run my application in visual studio its perfect.But when i deployed it into IIS it throws me an error saying that the access denied to a particular file.

My app reads a xml file based on the input(which is nothing but the other system in the network).As i browsed to the properties of that file manually and unchecked the read only attribute,still it dint work out.Can any one guide me to the proper solution ?

Comment: Probably a simple permissions error, but you need to describe what exactly the error says, and on what file, and how you are accessing it!  It isn't clear whether you mean you get this error when you go to the site, or if your script runs and gets an error later.  Also, are you using basic auth, or some other built-in authentication for IIS?

Comment: I am using the basic authentication here .System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\TestApp\Error\ErrorLog.txt' is denied. this is the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might have to give read/write (if needed) to following users:

1. iis_wpg
2. network service
3. aspnet

Comment: read/write permissions to the file i am reading ? i gave but it gets back to the readonly mode ?

Comment: try to apply it to the parent or root folder/directory. after you set the rights on the parent directory then replace all the rights on the child object check this out and make sure to check the replace child rights.....  http://min.us/lbV4ou

Answer (score 1):

In IIS, your site runs under the credentials of the application pool assigned to it. You can either change the credentials of your application pool to an account that has permission to access that file, or else grant access to the default account that the application pool is currently using.

Answer (score 1):

You mention that you are using basic auth...

Generally, the web application will then impersonate the user logged in.

So, if your file isn't accessible by the user that logged in, then it won't be accessible to the web application impersonating them on the system either.  You will need to check the permissions of those files and set them accordingly.